# Image button change all image with class

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image `onclick` that will change all the image `scr` into the image that is selected but it's not working. I didn't see any problem.

````html
```
<style>
  .mySlides {
    width: 50px;
    height 30px;
  }

  #View-Post-List-1,
  #View-Post-List-2 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 23px;
  }

</style>
<div id="View-Post-Image">
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-1" src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/72975551.cms?width=680&height=512&imgsize=881753" style="display: block;" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-2" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="#" />
</div>
<div id="View-Post-Listing">
  <ul id="View-Post-List">
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-1" src="https://cdn.eso.org/images/screen/eso1625a.jpg" 
       onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides').src = 'https://cdn.eso.org/images/screen/eso1625a.jpg';" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-2" src="https://cdn.eso.org/images/screen/eso1322a.jpg" 
       onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides').src = 'https://cdn.eso.org/images/screen/eso1322a.jpg';" alt="#" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```
````

There I did the snippet that you wanted to see I change it into two so it would not be long question. I did this with a id but i want to do with a class.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns array. You have to loop it. Or use jQuery `$('.mySlides').attr('src', '...')`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant script and CSS. You can even add images from placeholder.com

Comment: Perhaps you meant `onclick="document.getElementById(this.id.replace('List','Image')).src = this.src"`

Comment: Can you add a working snippet ? This should be achievable in a nicer way I guess rather than 2 much hardcoding

Comment: @Justinas how can i loop it

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. The code in onclick is good - but the class given in it (mySlides) refers to many elements. You should specify another class or id.

Example code:

```html
<li><img id="img" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ykuq3KjWWVgwt9fV1zh1ZzAhXJF6pKV5tbUGH0BZIBBP5yIICcavfO-knvLifR1rv0uBiEnlngw=w640-h400-e365" onclick="document.getElementById('img').src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT0iFDhKf3P2tJzwmzFkj9LqE0QkeAwLNfq8g&usqp=CAU'" alt="#"/></li>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: OP has an inline onclick event handler  - what do you mean by `You have no onclick function` Also w3schools is not a great resource

Comment: Maybe you don't understand me very well. I use an online translator :/

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer anything, also have false information in it. onClick can definitively be used instead of addEventListener in some scenarios. Such as "only do one thing" scenarios.

Comment: `"Onclick" can't work when there's nothing to call` - makes no sense, likely not in your native language either. OP has onclick="something that will execute"

Comment: i use it many times of my project it work perfectly find

Comment: Today you will use `document.addEventListener` (eg. click)

Comment: somthing like this but changing all images

Comment: It changes all the photos because they have an ID `img`. To each photo you have to add a different ID in the element and in the `onclick`. Then it will change one photo at a time. If you want to change more than 1 photo at a time, use the same ID in the `onclick`.

Answer (score -1):

*Edit: My previous answer was grounded on a misunderstanding.*

If you mean to change every image in `View-Post-Image` div after clicking an image within in the `View-Post-List`, then this might be what you seek:

```html
<div id="View-Post-Image">
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-1" src="img-POST/162x162-2.jpg" style="display: block;" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-2" src="img-POST/192x128-1.jpg" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-3" src="img-POST/192x128-2.jpg" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-4" src="img-POST/192x128-4.jpg" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-5" src="img-POST/192x128-3.jpg" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-6" src="img-POST/192x128-5.jpg" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-7" src="img-POST/192x128-6.jpg" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-8" src="img-POST/192x128-7.jpg" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-9" src="img-POST/192x128-8.jpg" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-10" src="img-POST/192x128-9.jpg" alt="#" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="View-Post-Image-11" src="img-POST/162x162-1.jpg" alt="#" />
  <button id="View-Post-Image-GoLeft" type="Button" class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;
  </button>
  <button id="View-Post-Image-GoRight" type="Button" class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;
  </button>
</div>
<div id="View-Post-Listing">
  <ul id="View-Post-List">
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-1" src="img-POST/162x162-2.jpg" onclick="selectImageFrom(this);" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-2" src="img-POST/192x128-1.jpg" onclick="selectImage(this);" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-3" src="img-POST/192x128-2.jpg" onclick="selectImageFrom(this);" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-4" src="img-POST/192x128-3.jpg" onclick="selectImageFrom(this);" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-5" src="img-POST/192x128-4.jpg" onclick="selectImageFrom(this);" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-6" src="img-POST/192x128-5.jpg" onclick="selectImageFrom(this);" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-7" src="img-POST/192x128-6.jpg" onclick="selectImageFrom(this);" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-8" src="img-POST/192x128-7.jpg" onclick="selectImageFrom(this);" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-9" src="img-POST/192x128-8.jpg" onclick="selectImageFrom(this);" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-10" src="img-POST/192x128-9.jpg" onclick="selectImageFrom(this);" alt="#" /></li>
    <li><img id="View-Post-List-11" src="img-POST/162x162-1.jpg" onclick="selectImageFrom(this);" alt="#" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
function selectImageFrom(listing) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.myslides').forEach(image => {
    image.src = listing.src;
  });
}
</script>
```

Basically what it does, is getting every image from `View-Post-Image` and setting its src to the image you click on from the `View-Post-List` div.

`selectImageFrom(this)` "this" means the current clicked div.

`querySelectorAll` returns an array of divs that contains the class "myslides". forEach is a loop that goes through every div, and lastly "src" is the attribute that you wish to set.

Comment: @mplungjan apologizes, I misunderstood the question. I think I follow now, otherwise please do update the post to be more elaborative of the expected behaviour.